# Add 1 to a last inserted id of a row in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to add one to the last inserted value of a column in a the database. I am not getting any error but the query is not adding 1 to the last inserted value.

Note; I used `MAX(id)` to get the max id but it's not adding 1 to it. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $pin = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['pin']));
    $surName = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['surName']));
    $firstName = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['firstName']));
    $otherName = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['otherName']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
    $passWord = md5(trim($_POST['passWord']));
    $confirmPass = md5(trim($_POST['confirmPass']));
    $date_added = date('Y.m.d - H:i:s');
    $year = (100 . 'L');
    $studentId = 201600001;

   if ((empty($pin && $surName && $firstName && $otherName &&      $email && $passWord && $confirmPass) == false) && ($passWord) == ($confirmPass))
{
 include "dbconnect.php";
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sono` WHERE `pin`='$pin'";   
 $check = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
 $numrow = mysqli_num_rows ($check);
 if ($numrow == 1)
 {
     $rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
     $Email = $rows['eMail'];
     if ($Email == false)
     {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM `sono` WHERE `eMail`='$email'";
         $check = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
         $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($check);
         if ($numrow == 0)
         {

                 $sql = "INSERT INTO `sono_nextofkin` (`eMail`) VALUES ('$email')";
                 mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
                 $query = "INSERT INTO `sono_0level_results` (`eMail`) VALUES ('$email')";
                 mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
                 $query = "UPDATE `sono` SET `surName`='$surName', `firstName`='$firstName', `otherName`='$otherName', `eMail`='$email', `passWord`='$passWord', `confirmPass`='$confirmPass', `date_added`='$date_added', `year`='$year', `studentid`='$studentId' WHERE `pin`='$pin'";
                 mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
                 $max = "SELECT * MAX(`studentid`) FROM `sono`";
                 $max2 = mysqli_query ($dbconnect, $max);
                 $update = "UPDATE `sono` SET `MAX(`studentid`) = '$studentId' + 1 WHERE `pin`='$pin'";
                 mysqli_query ($dbconnect, $update);                     
                 $query = "SELECT `id` as idmax FROM `sono`";
                 $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
                 $rowa = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                 $rw = $rowa['idmax'];
                 $rwo = $rw+1;
                 $rwo = str_pad($rwo,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
                 $sql = "UPDATE `sono` SET `id`='$rwo' WHERE `pin`='$pin'";
                 $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
                 $_SESSION['surName'] = $surName;
                 $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
                 $_SESSION['otherName'] = $otherName;
                 $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                 $_SESSION['passWord'] = $passWord;



                 $msg= "<p style = 'color: green; padding-left: 0'>Registration successful,<a href='passport.php'> >>>Click here to proceed<<<</a></p>";
                 } else
                 $msg= "<p style = 'color: red; padding-left: 0'>Email already used, use another valid email to register</p>";
                 } else
                 $msg= "<p style = 'color: red; padding-left: 0'>The pin has been used</p>";
                 } else
                 $msg= "<p style = 'color: red; padding-left: 0'>The pin enter does not exist</p>";
                 } else
                 $msg= "<p style = 'color: red; padding-left: 0'>Please enter your names, pin, email and password to start registration</p>";

  }
  ?>
```

Comment: You should never tinker with autoincremented id. Leave this value alone and never add any numbers to it

Comment: Thanks... But I have another id with autoincrement. The Id I am referring to for now is not autoincremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do like

```
$update = "UPDATE `sono` SET `studentid` = MAX(`studentid`) + 1 WHERE `pin`='$pin'";
```

OR

Use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) from your SQL query.

OR

You can also use [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get it using PHP.

Comment: Thanks... Could you please be more elaborate. Which one will I add one to. Is it the column I selected or the value I want to insert/update?

Comment: its general Query to update any column value by one but make sure column is of type numeric

Comment: UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = MAX(`column_name`) + 1 WHERE conditions

Comment: Thanks... I have tried this but I don't just know why it's not adding one to it. Please is there any other option?

Comment: check more solutions added by editing existing answer. LAST_INSERT_ID() from your SQL query. OR mysqli_insert_id() to get it using PHP.